# audio player starts song from the begging after click on progress bar in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I use [js audio player](https://osvaldas.info/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly) . my problem is that after song starts playing, if I click on progress bar, the song starts from the beginning (so it doesn't fast forward nor rewind, it just starts from beginning). I also try 2 DIFFERENT javascript audio players, but the problem is the same. I thought it may cause of my internal js and css files, I removed them but it doesn't help. maybe someone had the same problem and can help me.

here my html

```
<audio preload="none" controls>
   <source src="{{ asset('uploads/music/audio.ogg') }}"/>
</audio>
```

I'm sorry if i cannot clearly explain my problem.

Comment: did you try with the native html5 player? Also, try with a desktop player (it may be the audio file)

Comment: thank you for reply. i tried it with native html5 and it doesn't fast forward nor rewind, just stay at the current position, but now it doesn't start from the beginning

Comment: on desktop player it works(as it should)

Comment: hmmm did you try using another audio file? even with a different extension? sometimes happens, even with video files, if there is only a little bit corruption in the file, the player could not be able to fast forward

Comment: now I try it with firefox and it works. at first i use google chrome (chromium)

Comment: maybe it's an issue with the codec. try with a file with a different codec and see if it works.

Comment: i dont know exactly why that happened, because when I uploaded files on server it works, even at chromium browser. anyway, thanks for help